# How to access router queries in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to pass a value parameters in my URL, my mounted is like this

```
  mounted () {
    this.$router.push({
      path: '/activatewithphone',
      query: { serial: this.$route.params.serial, machine: this.$route.params.machine }
    })
  },
```

My computed

```
  computed: {
    serial () {
      return this.$route.query.serial
    },
    machine () {
      return this.$route.query.machine
    }
  },
```

I get serial and machine value like this

```
this.serial and this.machine
```

The problem here is when a user visits a URL like this

```
example.com/activatewithphone?serial=sddsdsds&machine=sdsdsd
```

It redirects back to `example.com/activatewithphone`

Serial and machine are dynamic

When I tried to get the value of serial with `this.serial and this.machine`

It returned `undefine`

The general idea of the app is

> Here is it, the user click on a link on the desktop to activate his
> account, the desktop app include parameters (serial and machine) to
> the URL and this launch a browser, the user enter form number and make
> payment on the web. Then I sent reference code back to the backend
> with the serial and machine that was sent with the URL. Is this clear
> now?

Comment: in `nuxt.config.js` what's the value of `target`?

Comment: The target is static

Comment: Could you explain a bit what are you trying to do exactly? Since having the user come to a page before being moved to the exact same page is a bit strange IMO. Also, where are you trying to get `this.serial`? A [repro] and clear explanation would really help achieving this in no time. :)

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `this.$route.query.serial`?

Comment: Here is it, the user click on a link on the desktop to activate his account, the desktop app include parameters (serial and machine) to the URL and this launch a browser, the user enter form number and make payment on the web. Then I sent reference code back to the backend with the serial and machine that was sent with the URL. Is this clear now?

Comment: It's working now. I changed, this.$route. params.machine to his.$route.query.machine
@kissu thanks

Comment: Did not get the difference between the desktop app and the need to launch a browser. What is actually the desktop here, an electron app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so it was basically a typo.

OP used `this.$route.params.serial` rather than `this.$route.query.serial`.